# about viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok I have got `ViewState["AddressID"]` and this `ViewState["AddressID1"]` both storing *AddressIDs*..Now if I want something like :-

```
if its ViewState["AddressID"]    
{
   call method 1
}

if its ViewState["AddressID1"]    
{
   call method 2
}
```

now how do I check if its `ViewState["AddressID"]` or `ViewState["AddressID1"]`?

Comment: what do you even mean? check if it's null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string addressId = ViewState["AddressID"] as string;
string addressId1 = ViewState["AddressID1"] as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressId))
{
    method1(addressId);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressId1))
{
    method2(addressId1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If a `ViewState` key doesn't have a value it is null, so:

```
if (ViewState["AddressID"] != null) 
  Method1(ViewState["AddressID"] as string);
else 
  Method2(ViewState["AddressID1"] as string);
```